# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level error writing a Python program in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, windows-10

Context: I test a sites performance and basic functionaitly on popular browsers: Ex: links, images, login/out experiences. 
I have pycharm as the editor on windows 10 pro and on a Mac.
When i run a script on windows 10 pro that simply opens the browser, gets the website I want to open; I get an indentation error where there isn't any indentation in said script.

The script:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie("/path/to/drivers/IEDriverServer.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Firefox("/path/to/drivers/geckodriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to /drivers/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://imgur.com/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/path/to/file/Base.py", line 2, in <module>

    from selenium import webdriver

  File "C:\path\to\file\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>

    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa

  File " C:\path\to\file \site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>

    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver

  File " C:\path\to\file \site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 715

    if self.w3c:
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this indentation error on only Windows 10 Pro? This is not a problem on mac

Comment: Have you recently started using any new text editors such as notepad++ ? The tabs may vary over there allowing these errors to flow through.

Comment: no, I manually typed it out referencing the script on the mac, spelling and syntax has been double and triple checked.

Answer (score -2):

This error message...

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
Process finished with exit code 1
```

...implies there is a mixup of Tab<\kbd> and Space<\kbd> characters within your program written in [pycharm](/questions/tagged/pycharm) IDE.

Apparently, I don't see any mixup of `Tab` and `Space` characters in your program. But as you are using *PyCharm* as the IDE beyond  adjusting the **tabs** and **spacing** you need to figure out if `~/.editorconfig` file that was overriding the pycharm configuration and you have to disable it.

Comment: The error is clearly shown as appearing *within the library file*. This can indicate that a version of a library intended for Python 2.x (which unwisely, but legally mixed tabs and spaces) is now being tried out in 3.x (where it shouldn't be expected to work regardless).